# multiple send on httplib.HTTPConnection, and multiple read on HTTPResponse?

Tags: python, http

Should it be possible to send a plain, single http POST request (not chunk-encoded), in more than one segment?  I was thinking of using `httplib.HTTPConnection` and calling the `send` method more than once (and calling `read` on the response object after each `send`).

(Context: I'm collaborating to the design of a server that offers services analogous to transactions [series of interrelated requests-responses]. I'm looking for the simplest, most compatible HTTP representation.)

Answer (score 1):

After being convinced by friends that this should be possible, I found a way to do it.  I override `httplib.HTTPResponse` (n.b. `httplib.HTTPConnection` is nice enough to let you specify the `response_class` it will instantiate).

Looking at socket.py and httplib.py (especially `_fileobject.read()`), I had noticed that `read()` only allowed 2 things:

- read an exact number of bytes (this returns immediately, even if the connection is not closed)
- read all bytes until the connection is closed

I was able to extend this behavior and allow free streaming with just a few lines of code.  I also had to set the `will_close` member of my HTTPResponse to 0.

I'd still be interested to hear if this is considered acceptable or abusive usage of HTTP.